# Correction for error: - required:spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable

Tags: scala, spray

I'm new to Scala, and trying to write a little REST API. I am using Scala 11.2, Spray 1.3.1 and akka 2.3.6.

I am basically trying to compile an example from spray.
The error I get for each of the routes is:
type mismatch; found : String("pong!!!!!!!!") required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable

I am unsure if it is a versions incompatibility issue or I am missing a reference.

Here is my route definition taken from the spray example :

```
package com.Shenandoah.SBIR.httpInterface


    import spray.routing.HttpService

    trait HttpInterface extends HttpService {  


      def pingRoute = path("ping") {
        get { complete("pong!!!!!!!!") }
      }

      def pongRoute = path("pong") {
        get { complete("pong!?") }
      }

        def pipRoute = path("pip") {
        get { complete("moonshine") }
      }

      def rootRoute = pingRoute ~ pongRoute ~ pipRoute
    }

    Here is the actor:

    package com.Shenandoah.SBIR.httpInterface

    import akka.actor._

    class HttpInterfaceActor extends HttpInterface with Actor {
      // the HttpService trait defines
      // only one abstract member, which connects the services environment
      // to the enclosing actor or test.
      def actorRefFactory = context


      def receive = runRoute(rootRoute)
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the dependency `"io.spray" % "spray-routing" % "2.3.6"` which is for Scala 2.10. There is a Spray version published without the Scala version designation, which is compiled against Scala 2.10. This is unfortunate.

Use `"io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % "2.3.6"` (note the double `%`) to pull in the dependency matching your Scala version. This will work with both Scala 2.10 and 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the default marshallers.  Try adding to your imports:

```
import spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller
```